# cocos2D game crashes when trying to remove child

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

in the init-method I initialize a NSMutableArray holding 4 images. I use this code to radomly place out the sprites (images):

```
_obstacles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:TOTAL_OBSTACLES_PER_WALL];
for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_OBSTACLES_PER_WALL; i++)
{

        obstacle = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:obstaclesTxt];

        int minX = obstacle.contentSize.width/2;
        int maxX = winSize.width-obstacle.contentSize.width/2;
        int xRange = maxX-minX;
        int minY = obstacle.contentSize.height/2;
        int maxY = winSize.height-obstacle.contentSize.height/2;
        int yRange = maxY - minY;
        randomXloc = (arc4random() % xRange) + minX;
        randomYloc = (arc4random() % yRange) + minY;

        obstacle.position = ccp(randomXloc, randomYloc);

        [_wall2 addChild:obstacle];
}
```

Then, in an update-method, if _wall2 leaves screen to the left (it is continously scrolling from right to left) the obstacles should be removed.

```
if (_wall2.position.x+_wall2.boundingBox.size.width <- 0)
{
    _wall2.position = ccp(_wall.boundingBox.origin.x+_wall.boundingBox.size.width+1, 0);

    [obstacle removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

When I run the app, the images are placed out randomly, but when the _Wall2 leaves the screen the app crashes. 
My question is if it is anything wrong with this code?

Comment: not using ARC ? you should retain (and later release) _obstacles. What is _obstacles used for (you are not modifying its content) ? What is 'obstacle' set to before entering the 'if' of the bottom snippet ?

Comment: What do you mean with "set to"?

Comment: where do you set it ?  ie obstacle = ??? ... show more code maybe.

Comment: ah I set it in the `obstacle` is shown in the code. The `_obstacles`array is also show in the code above

Comment: and what is your `obstacle` in "an update-method"? local variable, ivar, somethng else?